# Separated index vs merged index

Tags: mysql

Assume there is a table with three columns, none of them being the primary key, and there are 2 million records in the table for which the combination of three columns should be unique.

Is it better to make each one of columns index, or have merged index of all three columns?

Comment: Indexes have to be used **on purpose**, not "just in case", mind you

Comment: Also, your database is called mysql, not mysqli

Comment: @YourCommonSense so purpose is having a faster search on table. is it good or not to have merged index ?

Comment: "having faster search" is not a purpose but a wish.

Comment: oh my god i just asked which one is better. separated index or merged. you talk about wish!!! thanks for reply. but if you don't have any useful reply, there is no need to answer.

Comment: there is no abstract better. each better for its purpose. that's the point. you have to ask a useful question to get a useful reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the combination should be unique, then set up an *unique* index over the three columns.
Then the mysql-server will reject any further dataset with the same three columns after the first one.

Additionally, a search is faster when it is beeing run against the indexed columns.

And, last but not least, if you do only a select-statement of the indexed columns, the mysql-server doesn't need to read the table itself but only the index as it already includes all information. That would be the fastest way.